# Finding distance between document border and table in Word VSTO Add-In

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm trying to find distance in pixels between left border of Word document and left border of table in VSTO.

I've already tried the following:

```
int height = table.Range.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary];

// This isn't working - there is no get_information method in Range object
Word.Range range = table.Rows[1].Range;
int height = 
range.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber);
```

Is there any way to do it or VSTO prevents from operations on pixels relative to page?

Comment: I don't understand the comment "// This isn't working - there is no get_information method in Range object"? What does that mean, exactly, as there is definitely a method named `get_Information` for the Range object. Is it because the value isn't in pixels? Word is a word processing program, first and fore-most, which means it's print-oriented. By default, it doesn't measture things in pixels - those are a screen layout measurement. Why is a measurement in pixels important?

Comment: I used Information method on Range object. It seems that after some version of Interop lib, there's no get_information but instead Information property is available and works similarly. Problem solved - I used table.Range.Information[WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage]

Comment: that is odd... In the COM/VB-language world it's always the `Information` *property*. Since C# doesn't (didn't? has this changed?) support properties that take parameters the PIAs expose it as a *method* - `get_Information`. Perhaps it's the version of C# you're using and not the Office library? What combination of the two are you seeing this with?

Comment: Interop v15.0, .NET framework 4.6.1